# Would like to identify subnet names to create a map in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, maps, amazon-vpc, subnet

I've been trying to find a way to get the subnet names of out of aws... so far no luck.  I can find the arn, ids, cidrs... and a bunch of other stuff.  But, not names.  Help is appreciated!

This is what I'm aiming for.  To create a subnet map with the subnet name as the key, and the subnet id as the value.  Obviously name IS NOT a supported attribute of `data.aws_subnet`.  I have scoured the 'google' with not luck.

```
data "aws_subnets" "private" {
  tags = {
    Name = "private*"
  }
  filter {
    name   = "state"
    values = ["available"]
  }
}

data "aws_subnet" "private" {
  for_each = toset(data.aws_subnets.private.ids)
  id       = each.value
}

# wanting to create a map with subnet.name => subnet.id... but, name is an unsupported attribute.
private_subnet_ids = { for s in data.aws_subnet.private : trimprefix(s.name, "private") => s.id }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `tags["Name"]`:

```
private_subnet_ids = { for s in data.aws_subnet.private : trimprefix(s.tags["Name"], "private") => s.id }
```

Comment: Ah... I had switched the tag filter from filter block to tag, last minute... so, it hadn't sunk in that that was an option.  Thank you !